# Parsing two different formats of dates in data frame

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a column having 2 different formats of the date which I'm trying to convert to datetime using to_datetime of pandas 
Here's the code

```
import pandas as pa
pa.to_datetime(data["servertime"], format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

e.g - 
              servertime
Tue Nov  4 12:01:15 2014

***But few rows have data in following format 
u'2014-11-04 13:15:13 +0000'
which throws the errors***

How do I parse two different formats present in same row?

If I can't then how do I convert/remove/flag the rows(*preferably without hard coding* the condition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `to_datetime()`, first parse your strings with [`dateutil.parser.parse()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse):

```
In [2]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [3]: dt1 = "Tue Nov 4 12:01:15 2014"

In [4]: dt2 = "2014-11-04 13:15:13 +0000"

In [5]: parse(dt1)
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 4, 12, 1, 15)

In [6]: parse(dt2)
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 4, 13, 15, 13, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

You can then feed the `datetime.datetime` values into your dataframe.